# How would I write this in separate methods?

Tags: java, methods

I have a java project where I was told to write a program that asks the user to input a number of days and temperatures. From there I have to find the average temp, the days above average temp, as well as sorting the temperatures from highest to lowest. **I have done all of these things successfully, however, my professor is asking me to simplify my code by creating separate methods. For example, having a method for the days over the average, and so on. Although I understand the concept of this, I'm not sure how to approach and go about this way. ** Please help?

Here is the code that I have thus far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberAboveAverage {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter number of days of temperature to calculate:");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System. in);
        int day = keyboard.nextInt();
        int[] temperature = new int[day];

        System.out.println("Enter " + day + " temperatures to calculate.");

        for(int i=0; i<day; i++){
            temperature[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        int sum = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<day; i++){
            sum = sum + temperature[i];

        }

        int average = sum/day;
        System.out.println("The average temperature is: " + average); 

        int daysOver=0;
        for(int i=0; i<day; i++){
            if (temperature[i] > average){
                daysOver++;
            }   
        }
        System.out.println("The temperature was above average for " + daysOver + " day(s).");


            for (int i = 0; i < temperature.length; i++) {
                int min = i;
                for (int j = i; j < temperature.length; j++) {
                    if (temperature[j] < temperature[min])
                        min = j;
                }
                int temp;
                temp = temperature[i];
                temperature[i] = temperature[min];
                temperature[min] = temp;
            }

    System.out.print("The temperatures in increasing order are: ");
    for(int i=0; i<day; i++){
        System.out.print(temperature[i]+" ");
    }

}   
}
```

Comment: You'll also want to move (almost) everything out of `main()` and make the important variables instance fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to perform one task in a separate methods as below:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] temperature = new int[1];
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System. in);
    readTemperatures(keyboard, temperature);
    int sum = getSum(temperature);
    int average = sum/temperature.length;
    System.out.println("The average temperature is: " + average); 
    int daysOver=getDaysOver(temperature, average);
    System.out.println("The temperature was above average for " 
                                                         + daysOver + " day(s).");
    sortTemperature(temperature);
    printTemperature(temperature);
 }
```

and create methods as below:

```
private static void printTemperature(int[] temperature) {
    System.out.print("The temperatures in increasing order are: ");
     for(int i=0; i<temperature.length; i++){
        System.out.print(temperature[i]+" ");
     }
}

private static void readTemperatures(Scanner keyboard, int[] temperature){
       System.out.println("Enter number of days of temperature to calculate:");
       int day = keyboard.nextInt();
       temperature = new int[day];
       System.out.println("Enter " + day + " temperatures to calculate.");
       for(int i=0; i<day; i++){
        temperature[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
       }
}
```

Complete the rest of the methods.

Answer (score 3):

A good approach to decomposition of code is the same decomposition in english! You said it yourself:

> write a program that asks the user to input a number of days and temperatures. From there I have to find the average temp, the days above average temp, as well as sorting the temperatures from highest to lowest.

- Ask the user to input a number of days and temperatures
- find the average temp
- sort the tempatures

We can then turn this into code!

```
public static void main(String []args) {
  int[] temperature = getUserInput();
  int average = getAverage(temperature);
  int daysOver = getDaysOver(temperature, threshold);

  System.out.println("Average of : " + average + " with " + daysOver + " really hot days");
}
```

Now you can put your code in those functions, and print out whatever you like :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than answering your question for you in code, I'll give you some pointers.

You have a few functions you can abstract out.

- A function that calculates an average.
- A function that calculates the number of days over the average.
- A function that sorts the temperatures.
- A function that prints temperatures in order.

Answer (score 0):

Break your code up into steps that each solve a piece of the puzzle. For instance, have a method to calculate the average temperature, another method to calculate the days above the average temperature and another method to sort the temperatures in increasing order.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters pick some reasonably complete sequence of statements, eg:

```
int daysOver=0;
for(int i=0; i<day; i++){
    if (temperature[i] > average){
        daysOver++;
    }   
}
```

Figure out what parms you need to feed in and what result you need:

- day (maybe should call "numDays", but that's another discussion)
- temperature[]
- threshold (average)
- return daysOver

(I'm ignoring, for the nonce, the complexity/"optimization" that you can get `day` from the size of the array.)

So, a method might be:

```
computeDaysOver(int[] temperature, int average, int day) {
    int daysOver=0;
    for(int i=0; i<day; i++){
        if (temperature[i] > average){
            daysOver++;
        }   
    }
 }
```

But you need to specify a return type, and actually return it:

```
int computeDaysOver(int[] temperature, int average, int day) {
    int daysOver=0;
    for(int i=0; i<day; i++){
        if (temperature[i] > average){
            daysOver++;
        }   
    }
    return daysOver;
 }
```

And of course, you need to substitute your new method for where the original code was:

```
int daysOver = computeDaysOver(temperature, average, day);
```

Note that when selecting the operations to be included in a function it's important to "draw a circle around" operations with a limited number of inputs and outputs, and with a well-defined purpose.  Try to include a complete set of connected operations, not just an arbitrary set.

For instance, you might write a `computeAverage` function that encompasses the summation loop and the division.  You wouldn't normally have just the summation loop in a function and the division outside (or in a separate function) unless there was some separate need to compute just the summation.  And, if you did for some reason need the summation as a separate function, you'd make your `computeAverage` function invoke the summation function and then do the division, rather than passing in the sum as a parameter.

(These examples are rather trivial in this case, but the principles carry over to much larger and more complex blocks of code.)

Answer (score 0):

So why one use to break his code into different different method? It is because in order to separate different different logic/requirement, so that the `code becomes readable and  bug hunting becomes easy`.

In your case you have these things to do:

```
calculating the average will go into separate method.
sorting the temperatures-will go into separate method..
A method that prints temperatures in order.
```

For this reason methods have a return type. This means the after calculating and going through the logic, it will come with some output, So we can use return type of methods to get this value.

Now after that use can make object of your class like this

```
MyClass myClassObj = new MyClass();
```

And now call your methods using reference variable `myClassObj` like this

```
myClassObj.myMethod();
```

and save it into a variable if it returns something.

So if like `myMethod()` returns a `String` value so we can do like this to have the results of our `myMethod()` in the calling method:

```
String myStrVar = myClassObj.myMethod();
```